# How can uninstall norton security from my pc?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, uninstall

I accidentally installed Norton Security by installing Adobe Digital Edition via Chocolatey (It was a tick that I forgot to untick in the [Adobe Digital Edition installer](https://community.adobe.com/t5/digital-editions/unwanted-download-of-norton-security-scan-when-downloading-ade-4-5-4/td-p/8894942?page=1)). I am wondering I can uninstall it. I use windows 10 64 bit

Here is what I tried to do :

- Removing Adobe Digital Edition with Chocolatey

Adobe Digital Edition was successfully removed, but Norton was not.

- Looking at the Control Panel if there was a uninstaller for norton

There wasn't any uninstaller for Norton in the control panel

- Looking at the Norton files to see if the uninstaller was hidden in there

There wasn't any uninstaller when I searched for "uninstall"

- Looking at the start menu if the uninstaller

There was only the shortcut for uninstall Norton, I only found the Norton shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

#### I am wondering I can uninstall it.

> The [Norton Remove and Reinstall tool](http://liveupdate.symantecliveupdate.com/upgrade/RnR/NRnR.exe) can be used to:
>
> - Remove the current product and reinstall the latest version of Norton
> - **Remove Norton completely (Norton will not be automatically reinstalled)**

Source [Download and run the Norton Remove and Reinstall tool](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881)

Comment: I successfully got to removed Norton but when I open windows defender it says it use Norton.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? It allows you to just remove without reinstalling.

[Norton Remove and Reinstall Tool](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v60392881?client=norton&inid=nortoncom_nav_support.norton_homepage%3Ahome&site=nrtn_en_US&x=0&y=0)